# PHP array cannot loop back on itself?

Tags: php, sql, arrays

pretty new to php. I've got a function that's supposed to simulate an inning in a baseball game. This is the body of the php code:

```
define('DB_HOST', '************');
define('DB_USER', '******');    
define('DB_PASSWORD', '****');
define('DB_NAME', '******');

$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
if (!$conn) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
else {
    echo "connection established <br>";
}
$homeID = $_POST['home_team_ID'];
$awayID = $_POST['away_team_ID'];
echo "Home ID: $homeID";
echo "Away ID: $awayID";

$homeArray = array();  //Array that stores batting order for team
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM Z_PLAYERS WHERE teamID LIKE '$homeID'"); 
if (!$result){
    echo "Query to retrieve players from home team table failed.";
}
$playerArray = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$index = 0;     
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    $homeArray[$index] = $row;  //Here, the player rows are assigned to indices
    $index++;   
}
playInning($homeArray);  //function call
```

My playInning function is the problem. Here it is:

```
function playInning($homeArray){
    $hits = 0;
    $runs = 0;
    $outs = 0;
    $uptobat = 0;
    while ($outs < 3){
        $hitroll = rand(1, 1000);
        $hitchance = $homeArray[$uptobat]['playerAvg'];
        echo "Hitroll is $hitroll.<br>";
        echo "avg is $hitchance<br>";
        if($hitroll > ($homeArray[$uptobat]['playerAvg'])*1000){
            echo "HIT<br>";
            $hits++;
        }
        else {
            echo "OUT<br>";
            $outs++;
        }
        $uptobat++;
        if ($uptopbat > 8){
            $uptobat = 0; //Line doesn't seem to do what I want
        }
    }
}
```

Works well for the first 9 iterations. However, once $uptobat gets bigger than 8, and is reset to 0, I get no values for $homeArray[$uptobat][playerAvg] from there on out. The echo "avg is: $hitchance" prints out "avg is:   " ad infinitum.

It seems like this array does not like to be accessed in the same place more than once in a single loop? What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Array looks like this

```
$homeArray[1]->[playerID][playerFName][playerLName][playerAvg][teamID]

$homeArray[2]->[playerID][playerFName][playerLName][playerAvg][teamID]

$homeArray[3]->[playerID][playerFName][playerLName][playerAvg][teamID]

$homeArray[4]->[playerID][playerFName][playerLName][playerAvg][teamID]
```

...
Not sure how to illustrate php arrays. Does this make sense?

Comment: When you reset `$uptobat`, do you also need to reset `$outs`?

Comment: No, resetting `$uptobat` happens after the 9th hitter bats. Then, the leadoff hitter is up but the inning continues.

Comment: `[playerAvg]` should be `['playerAvg']` ?

Comment: should be, but shouldn't cause this error, i would need to see the array to help on this

Comment: Changed it for consistency to ['playerAvg']. Doesn't seem to make a difference with output though :/

Comment: Tried to represent the array. It's made up of rows from an SQL table that are mapped to indices.

Comment: You're skipping the first player because  `$playerArray = mysqli_fetch_array($result);` fetches the first row of the results, then the loop fetches the rest.

Comment: Just noticed this. You are right, that line is still there from an earlier test case. However, this is not my issue.

Comment: Your variable name is `$uptobat`but in this line `if ($uptopbat > 8){` you are checking variable `$uptopbat`. There is an extra **P** in the variable name!

Comment: SOLVED IT! I put `if $uptobat == 9` then `$uptobat = 0` at the beginning of the while loop. While my program now works, I have no idea what changed

Comment: EThan nailed it.. haha I dun gerfed bad